# Send email with php form

Tags: php, html, email

I am Using this Code in my contact Page for sending the mail but mail not sent this is creating a problem Please help me

```
<?php //code Start here
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $to = "abhishek@webistaan.com, info@webistaan.com"; // this is your Email address
   $email = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $comapny = $_POST['company'];
   $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
   $subject = "India Creatives";
   $message = $name . " \n" . $mobile . "\n" . $company . "\n" . $email . " Wrote:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
   //$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <info@indiacreatives.in>' . "\r\n";


$mailSuccess=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($mailSuccess)
{echo "Mail sent";}
else{
echo "not sent";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you get an error message? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: how much time did you take after run this code ? is it online or local ?

Comment: plz check with admin or network admin if php mailer is enabled in server? if php mailer is not working you can try using smtp method... Here might help...https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: not sent type error

Comment: `To:` field generally shouldn't list two recipients. Checking your MTA logs will tell you more.

Comment: @TarangP its online